# embedding woocommerce page breaking theme and not displaying correctaly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer

First I have contacted the theme developer and even paid for extra support and I am not getting any help. Thanks in advance for any help that you guys can give me

Issue:
When I embed a single product page using the **Visual Composer Woocommerce Product Page Element** on the home page the theme breaks. I've done this before on an older site using the same theme (Porto theme themeforest) and it worked fine. You can see it here: http://easypayold.wpengine.com/ (enter: UN: demo PW: 26d2d9153c32 to view site)

I am rebuilding the site and I am having the above issue.

I have disabled and activated all plugins to trouble shoot no changes. Then I activated the twentyseventeen them and embedded single product page worked so the issue seems to be from the theme itself.

I have removed the above single product page from the home page so you can see what it should look like then added it to a duplicate page so you can see how it is breaking the page. You can look at the home page to see the way it should look.

Duplicate page:
Name: !Home with Woocommerce embedded product page
URL: http://krankfinance.wpengine.com/home-2-2-2/

Home page the way it should look (with out single product)
http://krankfinance.wpengine.com/

Problems on home page:
 1. Full screen rows become boxed
 2. Reviews are gone (big issue)
 3. The embedded single product page (bottom of home page) is not displaying correctly.

Here you can see the stand alone single product page, the way it should look when embedded on home page:
http://krankfinance.wpengine.com/shop/easy-pay-formula-x-driver/

Thanks in advance. If you need any other info from me please ask.

Comment: I see this in console but I have no idea what to do about it:

(index):967 Uncaught TypeError: $tabs.easyResponsiveTabs is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):967)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):967
i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue (really more of a bandaid) by using an older version of my theme's woocommerce folder and putting it in my child theme. Then i removed the "Responsive Tabs js located porto(my theme)/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php

Really want it to work with the current theme's woocommerce though. Still no help from theme developer.